# Why to use OAuth2 Servers in Resource Owner Password Credential flow

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

For last few day I am reading through OAuth2 to figure out how to implement "Resource Owner Password Credentials" (Password grant) and came across following OAuth2 servers

1. [node-oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server)
2. [oauth2orize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2orize)

I explored these servers and got to know that, to implement Resource Owner Password Credential, **I need to feed following implementation to these servers**

1. Client Authentication
2. User Authentication
3. Token Generation(JWT)

But this made me think, what I am getting out of these servers ? What functionality/features they are providing or rather, why should I use them ?

Can anyone please help me understand what I am missing here ? Or all the OAuth2 servers out there work this way only and we have to feed them above 3 things ?

Please help, I am stuck here

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3

Comment: Yes, I have understood the flow. But I am just not able to understand what these OAuth servers offers me ? How do they help me here if I am doing all of the work (Authentication and Authentication using JWT tokens) ? What I am missing here ?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758151/oauth2-password-grant-with-node-js this to understand what I am up to. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Based on a quick read of the docs, they abstract the protocol, so you have to implement some logic, but don't need to worry about protocol compliance. If you want to have that all managed and just worry about configuration you should go for cloud authentication providers like Auth0 or social authentication providers like Google.

Comment: In my case I own every thing (client, user, resource server) and struggling with mapping OAuth server in my application but I really don't think going to some 3rd party OAuth server will make sense in my case.  Can you please let me know if I have to provide above mentioned 3 implementations if I stick to one of such OAuth server ?

Comment: @JoãoAngelo Please ignore above.

In my case I own every thing (client, user, resource server) and struggling with mapping OAuth server in my application but, I really don't think going to some 3rd party OAuth server will make sense in my case.  Can you please let me know if I have to provide above mentioned 3 implementations if I stick to one of such OAuth server. And if we think what I get out of these Server is that, my Authentication authorization will be OAuth compliant. Please correct me if I am wrong or missing something obvious.

Comment: You're correct, the main benefit would be to have an OAuth2 compliant implementation without having to get bogged in all the details.